# How to get a build to fail if project references are not as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

on my project someone recently changed project references as a hack to get something done. This caused CI build failures and other waste. Is it possible to create an msbuild task that can look at project references solution wide to check project references against a known good configuration, and for the build to fail in the case of unexpected changes. I realise this masks a deeper problem but the waste generated last time this happened is considered unacceptable and I've been asked to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: What kind of changes are you willing to track?

Comment: I'd like to have a build task that processes csproj files as XML if necessary to check that references in some projects do not include references to certain other projects. I'd have to have a white list or some kind of naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [msbuild inline task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx). This task will search for forbidden references inside files of type csproj and emit logs when it finds them. You could fail your build based on the task output HasForbiddenReferences.

This approach is usable if you want to execute the task one time to check for all csproj's. If you want to each project to check itself, you must alter the task to accept the project's path and do the checking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="CheckForbiddenReferences"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <SolutionDir ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <HasForbiddenReferences ParameterType="System.Boolean" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml.dll"/>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Linq"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[       

            HasForbiddenReferences = false;

            // Load your forbidden references here
            var forbiddenReferences = new[] { "Forbidden1", "Forbidden2", "Forbidden3" };

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(SolutionDir, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

            foreach (var f in files.Where(f =>
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(f));

                return doc
                        .Descendants(msbuild + "Reference")
                        .Union(doc.Descendants(msbuild + "ProjectReference"))
                        .Any(r => forbiddenReferences.Any(fr =>
                        {
                            var forbid = r.Attribute("Include").Value.Contains(fr);

                            if (forbid)
                                Log.LogMessage(string.Format("Forbidden reference {0} on Project {1}", fr, f));

                            return forbid;
                        }));

            }))
            {
                Log.LogMessage(string.Format("File {0} contains forbidden references", f));
                HasForbiddenReferences = true;
            }
            ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```

Call the task as usual:

```
<Target Name="CheckReferences" >
<CheckForbiddenReferences SolutionDir="$(SolutionDir)" >
     <Output PropertyName="HasForbiddenReferences" TaskParameter="HasForbiddenReferences" />
</CheckForbiddenReferences>

<Error Condition="$(HasForbiddenReferences)" Text="Build failed due to forbidden references"/> 

</Target>
```

Comment: FYI the `Error` task just calls `Log.LogError` internally, so you could just make that call instead of `LogMessage` and bothering with the `HasForbiddenReferences` property

Comment: I think I did that way so you could log the problems without failing the build.